# unificar filas con rowspan

Tags: php, html

tengo esta tabla que me trae datos de mysql por el momento la tengo asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que quiero es que en la columna día solo salga una celda que diga lunes en lugar de 6 veces lunes, en el momento esta así, me deja la ultima fila afuera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
no se si lo estoy poniendo mal o hay otra manera, el código es el siguiente:

```
    <?php 
            $materias = [];
            $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql) or trigger_error($db->error);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                // Si no existe el día, agregarlo
                if(!isset($materias[$row['id_dia']])) {
                    $materias[$row['id_dia']] = [];
                }
                // Agregar materia en el día correspondiente
                $materias[$row['id_dia']][] = $row;
            }

           {
           ?> 
    <div class="table-responsive">
            <table id="example3" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Dia</th>
        <th>Materia</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="myTable">
<?php
// Arreglo para mostrar nombre de día en vez de número
$dias = [1 => 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes'];
// Recorrer toda las materias
foreach($materias as $id_dia => $materias_dia) {
    echo '<tr>';
    // Mostrar columna del día con rowspan, basado en total de materias
    $rowspan = count($materias_dia);
    echo "<td align=\"center\" rowspan=\"$rowspan\">{$dias[$id_dia]}</td>";
    // Recorrer materias del día
    foreach($materias_dia as $materia) {
    echo '<tr>';
?>
        <td align="center"><strong>Clase:</strong> <?php echo $materia['nombre_materia']; ?><br>
        <strong>Docente:</strong> <?php echo $materia['nombre'] . ' ' . $materia['apellido']; ?><br>
        <strong>Aula:</strong> <?php echo $materia['nombre_salon']; ?><br>
        <strong><?php echo $materia['hora_inicial']; ?></strong> - <strong> <?php echo $materia['hora_final']; ?></strong></td>
<?php
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}

}
// Cerrar tabla
?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

gracias de antemano.

Comment: Al igual que en la otra respuesta, te recomiendo crear un arreglo donde almacenes las materias, esta vez con el día como índice, de forma que te permita contar cuántas materias hay en el día y asignar el atributo `rowspan` con ese valor.

Comment: Edita otra vez la pregunta y deja solo el código actual y la imagen con el resultado. Elimina todo lo anterior, para evitar confusiones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Igual que en la pregunta anterior, debo insistir en la optimización de consultas, realizando la petición sobre la tabla que contiene toda la información y "uniendo" las otras, quedando mucho más legible y manejable:

```
$sql = "SELECT mp.id_materia, mp.id_profesor, mp.id_curso, mp.hora_inicial, mp.id_dia,
        ma.nombre_materia,
        pr.nombre_profesor, 
        cu.nombre_curso
    FROM materia_profesor AS mp
    LEFT JOIN materias AS ma
        ON mp.id_materia = ma.id_materia
    LEFT JOIN profesor AS pr
        ON mp.id_profesor = pr.id_profesor
    LEFT JOIN cursos AS cu
        ON mp.id_curso = cu.id_curso
    WHERE mp.id_curso = '$id_mod2'
    ORDER by mp.id_dia, mp.hora_inicial";
```

Luego, hay que crear un arreglo con todas las materias, pero organizadas por día, de forma que puedas contar las que hay en cada día para unir la celda:

```
// Crear arreglo para materias, agrupados por día
$materias = [];
$result=mysqli_query($db,$sql) or trigger_error($db->error);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    // Si no existe el día, agregarlo
    if(!isset($materias[$row['id_dia']])) {
        $materias[$row['id_dia']] = [];
    }
    // Agregar materia en el día correspondiente
    $materias[$row['id_dia']][] = $row;
}

// Generar encabezados de la tabla
?>
    <table id="example3" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Dia</th>
        <th>Materia</th>
        <th>Hora de inicio</th>
        <th>Hora de fin</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="myTable">
<?php
// Arreglo para mostrar nombre de día en vez de número
$dias = [1 => 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes'];
// Recorrer toda las materias
foreach($materias as $id_dia => $materias_dia) {
    echo '<tr>';
    // Mostrar columna del día con rowspan, basado en total de materias
    $rowspan = count($materias_dia);
    echo "<td align=\"center\" rowspan=\"$rowspan\">{$dias[$id_dia]}</td>";
    // Recorrer materias del día
    foreach($materias_dia as $materia) {
?>
        <td align="center"><strong>Clase:</strong> <?php echo $materia['nombre_materia']; ?><br>
            <strong>Aula:</strong> <?php echo $materia['nombre_salon']; ?><br>
            <strong>Docente:</strong> <?php echo $materia['nombre'] . ' ' . $materia['apellido']; ?></td>
        <td align="center"><?php echo $materia['hora_inicial']; ?></td>
        <td align="center"><?php echo $materia['hora_final']; ?></td>
<?php
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}

// Cerrar tabla
?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: gracias estoy intentando replicarlo pero obtengo este error: **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\iedan\views\vistaHorario.php on line 425** es eta parte:  `foreach($materias_dia as $materia) {`

Comment: Cierto, en la línea anterior me faltó colocar `;` al final.

Comment: ya lo repliqué así, mejoro en que ya me muestra solo una vez cada día como quiero,  pero siguen saliendo una bajo de otra, editare la pregunta para que puedas ver como queda ahora, pero no se si debo cuadrar la matriz de otra manera, gracias por tu ayuda. ah y puse la hora inicial y final en la misma celda para que sea mas fácil de ver

Comment: Parece como que solo faltó `echo '</tr>';` después de recorrer materias del día.

Comment: si era eso, ya casi esta lo que pasa ahora es que el rowspan me esta tomando solo 5 de las 6 filas, me deja la ultima afuera, editare la pregunta con el código actual, gracias.

Comment: lo siento ya lo solucione, estaba mal ubicado el `echo '</tr>';` gracias

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre un arreglo pero no soluciona por completo tu problema.

Al recorrer el bucle *while* puedes asignar a una variable tu día de la semana, y si en la siguiente iteración el valor es el mismo, no escribir nada. Es decir:

Declaralo antes de empezar a recorrer tu array

```
$dia_semana = '';
while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
```

Introduce un ternario para comparar y en caso de que no sean iguales, lo imprimes. Sino, (si sigue siendo el mismo día), no imprimes nada

```
<td rowspan="6" align="center"><?php echo $mostrar['nombre_dia'] != $dia_semana ? $mostrar['nombre_dia'] : '' ?></td>
```

Antes de volver a la siguiente iteración, asigna el valor actual a tu variable *dia_semana*

```
<?php
$dia_semana = $mostrar['nombre_dia'];
}
?>
```

(he hecho el código a pelo, no obstante, aunque te falle, quedate con la idea).

---

Ahora, esto no te soluciona el problema de la altura que quieres tener para la celda. En este caso creo que deberías modificar tu consulta (o mejor, hacer otra consulta), para conocer cuantos lunes, cuantos martes, ....vas a traer de la consulta. Entonces, con esos valores conocidos, si son 4 lunes, 6 martes, etc... deberás asignar esos valores a los *rowspan* cada vez que hubiese un cambio en el día a mostrar. Podrías hacerlo (por ejemplo) almacenando estos valores en un array, y luego cada vez que se detecte un cambio de día ir asignando el valor que corresponda del array.

Es sólo una forma. Supongo que alguien podrá aportarte algo incluso mejor.

Answer (score 0):

Debes usar el atributo `rowspan` pero no puedes repetir la columna en tus siguientes interaciones, hasta encontrar un día diferente.

Mira el ejemplo, se aplica `rowspan="2"` a la primera  `tr` pero dado que el valor es `2` no se debe mostrar en el segundo `tr` por lo tanto lo encierro como comentario.

```html
<table>
<thead>
<th>Dia</th>
<th>Dato</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<!-- inicia día-->
<td rowspan="2">Lunes</td>
 <!-- fin día-->
<td>Lorem dato..</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<!--<td>Lunes</td> -->
<td>Lorem dato..</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Paso 1: Conocer el valor de `rowspan` debes saber cuantas veces se repite un día, para eso
vamos a mapear el resultado en otro array `$tabla` , almacenando como clave el valor del día.

Paso 2: Usando un DOBLE CICLO, para el cual en el primero recorro los días usando `foreach` (dato que sus claves no son escalares si no letras) y en el segundo con un `for` los resultados.

Paso 3: Cuentos los resultados que tiene cada día, para conocer el valor de  `rowspan` solo muestro el valor del día para la primera columna ( posición cero ) usando `<!-- inicio día--> <td>...</td> <!-- fin día-->` y ocultado los siguiente con `<!-- <td>..</td> -->`

```php
 // paso 1
 $tabla = array()
 while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $tabla[$mostrar['nombre_dia']][] = $mostrar 
 }
// resultado $tabla[ 
//   "lunes" => array[ [] , [] , [] ]  ] ,
//   "martes" => array[ [] , [] , [] , [] ]  
// ]

// paso 2
foreach($tabla as $dia => $valores){
  $row_span = count($valores);
  for($i=0; $i < $row_span; $i++){
    $mostrar = $valores[$i]
?>
     <tr>
       <?php echo $i != 0 ? "<!--": "<!-- inicia día -->" ?>
       <td rowspan="<?=$row_span"> <?=$motrar['nombre_dia']?> </td>
       <?php echo $i != 0 ? "-->": "<!-- fin día -->" ?>
       <td> Clase: <?=$motrar['nombre_materia']?> </td>
     </tr>
<?php
  }
}
```

Nota: Es mas fácil mostrar o no mostrar la primera columna usando un `if` que aplicar comentarios en HTML para ocultarla asi:

```php
<?php
if($i == 0){
?> 
   <td rowspan="<?=$colspan?>"><?=$motrar['nombre_dia']?></td>
<?php
}
?>
```